# basic flutter question regarding the use of $ in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

Suppose I have declared expression like this

```dart
bool Smp0 = false;
bool Smp1 = false;
bool Smp2 = false;
```

and then I use a group button widget (a built-in check box)

```dart
onSelected: (index, IsSelected){print('$index dan $IsSelected');}),
```

where the index is a list between 0-2 and IsSelected is a bool between true and false (associate with the checkbox).

Now I want to put that index with associated IsSelected my idea is putting

```dart
Smp$index = $IsSelected;
```

But the problem is this expression doesn't work. I'm still not used to remember some dart/flutter code.. so anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You can't dynamically generate variable names.  Use a `List` of `bool`s instead (e.g. `var Smp = <bool>[];` and later `Smp[index] = IsSelected`). `$` is used for string interpolation and makes sense only within string literals.

Comment: although this isnt exactly an answer but it does help me creating an array so I can put my variables in order to submit to my back4app. so thx man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so yes. as james said it. I make own array with this.

```
class CheckBoxSetting {
  int index;
  String title;
  bool value;

  CheckBoxSetting({
    this.index,
    this.title,
    this.value,
  });
}
```

the content with this

```
final notification = [
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Kertas', index: 0, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Kaca', index: 1, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Elektronik', index: 2, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'BesiLogam', index: 3, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Plastik', index: 4, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Alumunium', index: 5, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Fabric', index: 6, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Kayu', index: 7, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Bio', index: 8, value: false),
    CheckBoxSetting(title: 'Mix', index: 9, value: true),
  ];
```

and finally in group button I made this (not I declare few expression as I need that expression in order to be use inside back4app)

```
onSelected: (index, IsSelected) async {
                              notification[index].value = IsSelected;
                              if (A0 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab0 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A1 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab1 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A2 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab2 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A3 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab3 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A4 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab4 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A5 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab5 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A6 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab6 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A7 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab7 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A8 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab8 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                              if (A9 == notification[index].title){
                                Ab9 = notification[index].value;
                              };
                            }),
```

A0-9 and Ab0-9, I know it is a long code, but IT DOES WORK, that is what matter most. thx to @jamesdlin for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Dart String Interpolation

You can access the value of an expression inside a string by using ${expression}.

```html
var greeting = "Hello";
var person = "Kannan";

print("${greeting}, ${person}!"); // prints "Hello, Kannan!"
```

If the expression is an identifier, the {} can be skipped.

```html
print("$greeting, $person");
```

If the variable inside the {} isn’t a string, the variable’s toString() method is called:

```html
int x = 5;
print("There are ${x.toString()} people in this room");
```